# Updating Table Field With An Array In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to uapdate a table field with an array.That means i have a table with name `test`.In that table i inserted some rows first.

After some process i want to update a filed in this table with ana array value.When i inserting rows into this table at that time this filed is set to `0`.

After some process some values returned to a variable `$var` like:

```
Array
(
    [id] => "http://www.google.com/calendar/"
    [etag] => "GEwNTgxHfip7JGA6WhJV"

    [link] => "http://www.google.com/calendar/"

)
```

This is the code iam using for updating field:

```
$idg= json_encode($var);
mysql_query("UPDATE `test` SET `tk` = '$idg' WHERE `TID` =10");
```

The above code is the edited code .The `$idg` now have:

```
{"id":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/testid%40gmail.com\/events\/64h9vc0qqqtlqeqhudhhdqbsds","etag":"\"GEwCQwxGeSp7JGA6WhJV\"\r","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/testid%40gmail.com\/private\/full\/64h9vc0qqqtlqeqhudhhdqbsds\r"}
```

After excuting this code the field will updated with `null` value.This is the problem facing now.

Comment: your `$var` is an array. you need to access one of its element. like `$var['id']`

Comment: you mean i cant to update the $var array completely into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your table column can only contain a scalar value you have to convert the array into some string representation, e.g. via [json_encode()](http://docs.php.net/json_encode).
When you fetch the value from the table again you have to convert it back, in this case via json_decode().

---

edit: or use a storage mechanism/database that can handle this type of data, e.g. a document based database like [mongodb](http://docs.php.net/mongodb).

---

edit2: add parameter encoding, error handling and debug code

```
<?php
echo "start\n";

$tid = 10;
$idg = json_encode($var);
$idg_sql = mysql_real_escape_string($idg);

$query = "
    UPDATE
        `test`
    SET
        `tk` = '$idg_sql'
    WHERE
        `TID` = $tid
";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ( !$result ) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

if ( 1 < mysql_affected_rows() ) {
    // debugging
    echo "no affected rows\n";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Count(*) as c FROM `test` WHERE `TID`=$tid") or die(mysql_error());
    while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}

echo "done.\n";
```

Comment: This is the query iam using with json data . **UPDATE `test` SET `gk` = '{"id":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/test%40gmail.com\/events\/f8uhsjkqvneqif0b0qucdetfog","etag":"\"GEwCRQZIfSp7JGA6WhJV\"\r","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/test%40gmail.com\/private\/full\/f8uhsjkqvneqif0b0qucdetfog\r"}' WHERE `TID` =91**.But it is not updated when excuted this query.But it is updated when i directly giving in phpmyadmin's sql.What is the reason for this?

Comment: we need _all_ the _relevant_ php code to answer this question... btw: if you store structured data in a single column your relational database won't be of much help if you want to query records based on the data in that column. E.g. a query like "How entered the link having the etag GEwCRQZIfSp7JGA6WhJV" will result in a full table scan + your php script doing the actual comparison.

Comment: @ VolkerK : Now i can update this value , But i cant to retrieve / display this value , What is the reason?

Comment: This is the code iam used to select value: ``$sql_sel_now = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `TID` = 10";
$res_sel_now = mysql_query($sql_sel_now);
$result_sel_now = mysql_fetch_row($res_sel_now);
$tk = $result_sel_now[20];
$jtk = stripslashes($tk);
$rtk = json_decode($jtk);
print_r($rtk);``.When iam print the value nothing will be displayed .What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Convert you array into a string representation using `json_encode()` then the obtained string can be easily stored in the DB table field

Answer (score 0):

To store whole array in database convert it to string by [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
and while reteiving it [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert array into string value then insert into the query. 
For example:

```
<?php

    $var = Array('id' => "http://www.google.com/calendar/",'etag' => "GEwNTgxHfip7JGA6WhJV",'link' => "http://www.google.com/calendar/");
    foreach($var as $var1){
    $string .= $var1.",";
    }
    $var = substr($string,0,-1);
    echo "UPDATE `test` SET `gk` = '$var' WHERE `TID` =77"; //printing query to check the values

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data in a string. 
You could either use php's serialize() function OR use json_encode() and json_decode() when needed.